# officejs react - how do I add another page?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, office-js, yo

I have created a Microsoft Office Add-in React (TypeScript) Project using [`yo office`](https://github.com/OfficeDev/generator-office)

How do I add another page? I want to create some additional UI which pops up in a dialog (ie. displayed using `Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync`) so no need for loading `officejs`

I tried to use `react-router` but I didn't manage to get it working... The way `index.tsx` works is a bit different from the normal `create-react-app` template that most tutorials use.

Comment: I haven't tried your scenario, but note that displayDialogAsync opens a completely separate instance of the browser/JS engine. It might be that you'll need a completely separate component pyramid in the dialog, almost a separate React app. The Office Dialog doesn't play easily with SPAs. Consider, using react-router _within_ the task pane, or using tabs (Fabric React Pivot control) within the task pane.

Comment: @RickKirkham - that's right - i need a completely separate component that is rendered on a separate page/route...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this by adding:

- a new tsx file for my page
- a new `HtmlWebpackPlugin` in `webpack.common.js` with a new `chunk` name
- an `entry` in `webpack.common.js` which links my `tsx` file with my `chunk`